# Hide section of a Parent component if child component is not generating any markup in Blazor App

Tags: blazor, blazor-webassembly

I have a parent component in Blazor in which child component is placed.

```
<div class="margin-top-50">
  <ChildComponent someparameters/>
</div>
```

Now if the child component is not generating any markup based upon parameters passed, I don't want to render the div tag also in the parent component. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

Would it be an option to put the outer div inside of `ChildComponent`?

Inside `ChildComponent.razor`

```
<div class="margin-top-50">
  ... the rest of the component as it is now
</div>
```

In case you render that component somewhere else, and you don't need the div there, then you can remove the margin in the component based on the passed in parameters - the same parameters that define whether there's any markup being generated.

Comment: No. the child component is used at multiple places and not possible to add the div in the child component, Is there another way to achieve this.